# How do I use several conditions with the SEARCH function in Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I need to search inside of strings for specific texts and need to search for several texts inside one string.

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Storm";L2))=TRUE;1;IF(ISBLANK(L2);0;""))
```

This is my formula with a single condition (Storm), I need more than one conditions that check if the text is in a string and output by the result of this a 1 or a blank.

Comment: Show an example or some Data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To search for a `string`in a separate cell you can use the `SEARCH` function...

```
SEARCH("STRING";CELL REF;1)
```

The value `STRING` is what you are searching for, the `CELL REF`is the `CELL` you are searching (a range of cells is OK).

To achieve the binary operator you are requesting you need to add nest the above formula into an `IF` statement and combine it with the `ISERROR` function.

```
=IF(ISERROR(SEARCH("STRING";CELL REF;1));0;1)
```

Example:

[image: Spreadsheet]

Add this equation to `Cell B1`

```
=IF(ISERROR(SEARCH("Storm";A1:A4;1));0;1)
```

[image]

This gives you the value `1` if the string is found in the range and a value `0` if it is not.

For several `strings`, use several nested `IF` statements.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, however, wildcards do not work in my case as the words I search for are not related to each other. I need to search for words such as Storm, lightning strike, flood, etc.

Comment: Please try the following formula:
=IF(ISERROR(SEARCH("STRING";CELL REF;1));0;1) This will return a 0 if the string is not found and a 1 if the string is found. If you need several strings then nest the IF. If this works I will update my answer.

Answer (score 0):

if you need to search for words such as XX, YY
=IF(A1="","",IF(AND(ISERROR(SEARCH("XX",A1)),ISERROR(SEARCH("YY",A1))),"OTHER",IF(ISERROR(SEARCH("XX",A1)),"YY","XX")))