# How to map value of a cell to another value, depending what it "contains" ? (not a full match)

Tags: worksheet-function, libreoffice-calc, vlookup

I have a worksheet `C1` with the following data:

| A | B |
| --- | --- |
| sometext 21 oscar ABC john |  |
| sometext 22 foo XXX smith |  |
| sometext 23 lucy YYY pedro |  |
| sometext 24 bar ZZZ edward |  |

In another worksheet `C2`, the following :

| A | B |
| --- | --- |
| XXX | 4 |
| YYY | 5 |
| ZZZ | 6 |

**I would like to check if `C1.A` contains any value of `C2.A`, and if yes, associate related value `C2.B` into `C1.B`**

| A | B |
| --- | --- |
| sometext 21 oscar ABC john | N/A |
| sometext 22 foo **XXX** smith | 4 |
| sometext 23 lucy **YYY** pedro | 5 |
| sometext 24 bar **ZZZ** edward | 6 |

What I have already tried is a VLOOKUP with some wildcards on the range but it does not work. It works with wildcards on the lookup value (first parameter) but that is not what I want :

```
VLOOKUP($C1.A1; "*" & $C2.A:B & "*", 2; 0)
```

Comment: Are "XXX", "YYY", "ZZZ", etc always at the end of the texts in C1?

Comment: No, it's not always the case. I will edit question to make it more clear

Comment: "I would like to check if C1.A contains any value of C2.A, and if yes, associate related value C2.B into C1.B" Looking at the result/output table, you will need give more details/explanation: C1.B and C2.B don't correspond, why is 4 shown as the result. OR are you searching for the text from C2 in the whole column, then if found, show its value?

Comment: 4 is shown because "sometext 22 foo XXX smith" contains "XXX"

Comment: OK. But is the check done 1 to 1 (meaning C1.B to C2.B) or 1 to many (meaning we need to check if any cell in C1 contains XXX).

Comment: in C1.B1, "sometext 21 oscar ABC john" is checked against "XXX", "YYY", "ZZZ". Then, in C1.B2, "sometext 22 foo XXX smith" is checked against "XXX", "YYY", "ZZZ" and so on...

Comment: What version of Excel do you have? And will the "sometext" strings ever contain multiple matches to the list in C2.A? For example, "sometext 22 XXX foo ZZZ smith"?

Comment: perhaps explore the excel fuzzy match add-in.

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14803944/excel-searching-for-multiple-terms-in-a-cell) is how to search multiple terms in a cell.. | for [identifying](https://superuser.com/a/1678408/268214) them.. idk.. sorry |

Comment: @DjC : I use `LibreOffice Calc 7.3.2.2 (x64)`. I have edited OP since it was incorrectly tagged as `Microsoft Excel`.

Comment: It seems to me that you are looking for something like `=SUMPRODUCT(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(C2.$A$2:$A$4;A2));C2.$B$2:$B$4)` ?